# Datatables individual column search on Enter key issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am having an issue with implementing Datatables with individual column search when pressing the Enter key.

At first, I implemented it using [Datatables guide](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) like this:

```
table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
```

The code above works fine. However, because the table uses server-side processing, it's too expensive to search on keypress.

So, I am attempting to change the code so that it searches on Enter key:

```
table.columns().every(function () {
    var that = this;

    $('input', this.footer()).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { //search only when Enter key is pressed to avoid wasteful calls
            e.preventDefault(); //input is within <form> element which submits form when Enter key is pressed. e.preventDefault() prevents this
            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                that
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

With the code above, if I write a search value and press Enter, it searches as expected. However, if I write a search value for `column1` but press enter on `column2`, it does not perform a search with the value in `column1`. This results in the user being required to press Enter on each column to add/delete the search value. The user is unable to first write search values in the desired columns and then press Enter on one of them to search.

From what I've been able to gather, the table stores the value and it's not updated until Enter is pressed on the specific column. I am not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with help. My Datatables is server-side with dynamically generated columns, so I needed to get the input value from each input box and search it for each column. I will update this answer as I understand more.

Here's the working code:

```
table.columns().every(function () {               
    $('input', this.footer()).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { //search only when Enter key is pressed to avoid wasteful calls
            e.preventDefault(); //input is within <form> element which submits form when Enter key is pressed. e.preventDefault() prevents this
            var header = table.table().header(); //header because I moved search boxes to header
            var inputBoxes = header.getElementsByTagName('input');
            $.each(data.columns, function (index) {
                var inputBoxVal = inputBoxes[index].value;
                table.column(index).search(inputBoxVal);
            });
            table.draw();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can approach this:

- Use [`activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement) to see what element have focus, and do the search accordingly.
- Set a timer after `keyup` on your original event, and do the search after some seconds:

  ```
  var searchTimer;

  table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;
    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
      if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
        clearTimeout(searchTimer); // Reset timer
        var value = this.value;
        searchTimer = setTimeout(function() {
          that.search(value).draw();
        }, 3000); // Wait 3 seconds
      }
    });
  });
  ```